# Enviar XML al web service de SII AEAT (PHP SOAP)

Tags: php, xml, webservice, aeat-sii

Ya ha sido preguntado, pero no encuentro respuesta... en una llamada al webservice de AEAT para envío de facturas, cómo se embebe el XML de envío? Alguien tiene un ejemplo completo de envío de facturas emitidas y otro de recibidas?

```
    $url = 'https://www7.aeat.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fe/SiiFactFEV1SOAP';

    $params1 = array( 
                "location"      => $url,
                "style"         => SOAP_DOCUMENT,
                "use"           => SOAP_LITERAL, 
                "trace"         => 1, 
                "exceptions"    => 0,
                "cache_wsdl"    => 0
            ); 
$soapclient = new SoapClient('https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroFactEmitidas.wsdl', $params1);

    var_dump($soapclient->funcion($parametros));
```

Answer (score 2):

Aquí te dejo un script completo que envía dos facturas emitidas al entorno de pruebas:

```
<?php

// Ejemplo script para facturas emitidas
// Ruta a certificado previamente convertido de PFX a PEM
$local_cert = 'C:\Projects\aeat-sii-desarrolladores\demo-script\certificados\ALEXANDRU_CATALIN_bundle.pem';

// URL definición servicio de facturas emitidas
$wsdl = 'http://www.agenciatributaria.es/static_files/AEAT/Contenidos_Comunes/La_Agencia_Tributaria/Modelos_y_formularios/Suministro_inmediato_informacion/FicherosSuministros/V_07/SuministroFactEmitidas.wsdl';

// Instanciar el cliente SOAP
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array(
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
    'trace' => true,
    'exceptions' => true,
    'local_cert' => $local_cert,
        ));

// Cambiar a entorno pruebas
$location = 'https://www7.aeat.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fe/SiiFactFEV1SOAP';
$client->__setLocation($location);

// Construir datos
$datos = array(
    'Cabecera' =>
    array(
        'IDVersionSii' => '1.0',
        'Titular' =>
        array(
            'NombreRazon' => 'ALEXANDRU CATALIN TRANDAFIR',
            'NIF' => 'X4378072E',
        ),
        'TipoComunicacion' => 'A0',
    ),
    'RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas' =>
    array(
        0 =>
        array(
            'PeriodoImpositivo' =>
            array(
                'Ejercicio' => '2017',
                'Periodo' => '12',
            ),
            'IDFactura' =>
            array(
                'IDEmisorFactura' =>
                array(
                    'NIF' => 'X4378072E',
                ),
                'NumSerieFacturaEmisor' => 'SIIDEMO/1',
                'FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor' => '31-12-2017',
            ),
            'FacturaExpedida' =>
            array(
                'TipoFactura' => 'F1',
                'ClaveRegimenEspecialOTrascendencia' => '01',
                'ImporteTotal' => 1210,
                'DescripcionOperacion' => 'Compra ordenador portátil',
                'FechaOperacion' => '31-12-2017',
                'Contraparte' =>
                array(
                    'NombreRazon' => 'HeavyDots SL',
                    'NIF' => 'B66544586',
                ),
                'TipoDesglose' =>
                array(
                    'DesgloseFactura' =>
                    array(
                        'Sujeta' =>
                        array(
                            'NoExenta' =>
                            array(
                                'TipoNoExenta' => 'S1',
                                'DesgloseIVA' =>
                                array(
                                    'DetalleIVA' =>
                                    array(
                                        0 =>
                                        array(
                                            'TipoImpositivo' => 21,
                                            'BaseImponible' => 500,
                                            'CuotaRepercutida' => 105,
                                        ),
                                        1 =>
                                        array(
                                            'TipoImpositivo' => 21,
                                            'BaseImponible' => 500,
                                            'CuotaRepercutida' => 105,
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
        1 =>
        array(
            'PeriodoImpositivo' =>
            array(
                'Ejercicio' => '2017',
                'Periodo' => '12',
            ),
            'IDFactura' =>
            array(
                'IDEmisorFactura' =>
                array(
                    'NIF' => 'X4378072E',
                ),
                'NumSerieFacturaEmisor' => 'SIIDEMO/2',
                'FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor' => '31-12-2017',
            ),
            'FacturaExpedida' =>
            array(
                'TipoFactura' => 'F1',
                'ClaveRegimenEspecialOTrascendencia' => '01',
                'ImporteTotal' => 1210,
                'DescripcionOperacion' => 'Compra ordenador portátil',
                'FechaOperacion' => '31-12-2017',
                'Contraparte' =>
                array(
                    'NombreRazon' => 'HeavyDots SL',
                    'NIF' => 'B66544586',
                ),
                'TipoDesglose' =>
                array(
                    'DesgloseFactura' =>
                    array(
                        'Sujeta' =>
                        array(
                            'NoExenta' =>
                            array(
                                'TipoNoExenta' => 'S1',
                                'DesgloseIVA' =>
                                array(
                                    'DetalleIVA' =>
                                    array(
                                        0 =>
                                        array(
                                            'TipoImpositivo' => 21,
                                            'BaseImponible' => 500,
                                            'CuotaRepercutida' => 105,
                                        ),
                                        1 =>
                                        array(
                                            'TipoImpositivo' => 21,
                                            'BaseImponible' => 500,
                                            'CuotaRepercutida' => 105,
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);

// Definir comando
$comando = 'SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas';

// Relizar llamada
$response = null;
$e = null;

try {
  $response = $client->$comando($datos);
} catch (Exception $e) {

}

if ($e instanceof Exception) {

  $error = $e->getMessage();
  $error_detalles = $e->getTraceAsString();

  echo('Error:');
  echo($error);
  echo '<br>';

  echo('Detalles error:');
  echo($error_detalles);
  echo '<br>';
}

$peticion_xml = $client->__getLastRequest();
$respuesta = $client->__getLastResponse();

echo('Petición:<br>');
echo '<pre>' . htmlentities($peticion_xml) . '</pre>';

echo('Respuesta:<br>');
echo '<pre>' . htmlentities($respuesta) . '</pre>';
```

Si lo ejecutas te imprimirá algo así en pantalla:

```
Petición:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroInformacion.xsd" xmlns:ns2="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroLR.xsd"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns2:SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas><ns1:Cabecera><ns1:IDVersionSii>1.0</ns1:IDVersionSii><ns1:Titular><ns1:NombreRazon>ALEXANDRU CATALIN TRANDAFIR</ns1:NombreRazon><ns1:NIF>X4378072E</ns1:NIF></ns1:Titular><ns1:TipoComunicacion>A0</ns1:TipoComunicacion></ns1:Cabecera><ns2:RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas><ns1:PeriodoImpositivo><ns1:Ejercicio>2017</ns1:Ejercicio><ns1:Periodo>12</ns1:Periodo></ns1:PeriodoImpositivo><ns2:IDFactura><ns1:IDEmisorFactura><ns1:NIF>X4378072E</ns1:NIF></ns1:IDEmisorFactura><ns1:NumSerieFacturaEmisor>SIIDEMO/1</ns1:NumSerieFacturaEmisor><ns1:FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor>31-12-2017</ns1:FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor></ns2:IDFactura><ns2:FacturaExpedida><ns1:TipoFactura>F1</ns1:TipoFactura><ns1:FechaOperacion>31-12-2017</ns1:FechaOperacion><ns1:ClaveRegimenEspecialOTrascendencia>01</ns1:ClaveRegimenEspecialOTrascendencia><ns1:ImporteTotal>1210</ns1:ImporteTotal><ns1:DescripcionOperacion>Compra ordenador portátil</ns1:DescripcionOperacion><ns1:Contraparte><ns1:NombreRazon>HeavyDots SL</ns1:NombreRazon><ns1:NIF>B66544586</ns1:NIF></ns1:Contraparte><ns1:TipoDesglose><ns1:DesgloseFactura><ns1:Sujeta><ns1:NoExenta><ns1:TipoNoExenta>S1</ns1:TipoNoExenta><ns1:DesgloseIVA><ns1:DetalleIVA><ns1:TipoImpositivo>21</ns1:TipoImpositivo><ns1:BaseImponible>500</ns1:BaseImponible><ns1:CuotaRepercutida>105</ns1:CuotaRepercutida></ns1:DetalleIVA><ns1:DetalleIVA><ns1:TipoImpositivo>21</ns1:TipoImpositivo><ns1:BaseImponible>500</ns1:BaseImponible><ns1:CuotaRepercutida>105</ns1:CuotaRepercutida></ns1:DetalleIVA></ns1:DesgloseIVA></ns1:NoExenta></ns1:Sujeta></ns1:DesgloseFactura></ns1:TipoDesglose></ns2:FacturaExpedida></ns2:RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas><ns2:RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas><ns1:PeriodoImpositivo><ns1:Ejercicio>2017</ns1:Ejercicio><ns1:Periodo>12</ns1:Periodo></ns1:PeriodoImpositivo><ns2:IDFactura><ns1:IDEmisorFactura><ns1:NIF>X4378072E</ns1:NIF></ns1:IDEmisorFactura><ns1:NumSerieFacturaEmisor>SIIDEMO/2</ns1:NumSerieFacturaEmisor><ns1:FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor>31-12-2017</ns1:FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor></ns2:IDFactura><ns2:FacturaExpedida><ns1:TipoFactura>F1</ns1:TipoFactura><ns1:FechaOperacion>31-12-2017</ns1:FechaOperacion><ns1:ClaveRegimenEspecialOTrascendencia>01</ns1:ClaveRegimenEspecialOTrascendencia><ns1:ImporteTotal>1210</ns1:ImporteTotal><ns1:DescripcionOperacion>Compra ordenador portátil</ns1:DescripcionOperacion><ns1:Contraparte><ns1:NombreRazon>HeavyDots SL</ns1:NombreRazon><ns1:NIF>B66544586</ns1:NIF></ns1:Contraparte><ns1:TipoDesglose><ns1:DesgloseFactura><ns1:Sujeta><ns1:NoExenta><ns1:TipoNoExenta>S1</ns1:TipoNoExenta><ns1:DesgloseIVA><ns1:DetalleIVA><ns1:TipoImpositivo>21</ns1:TipoImpositivo><ns1:BaseImponible>500</ns1:BaseImponible><ns1:CuotaRepercutida>105</ns1:CuotaRepercutida></ns1:DetalleIVA><ns1:DetalleIVA><ns1:TipoImpositivo>21</ns1:TipoImpositivo><ns1:BaseImponible>500</ns1:BaseImponible><ns1:CuotaRepercutida>105</ns1:CuotaRepercutida></ns1:DetalleIVA></ns1:DesgloseIVA></ns1:NoExenta></ns1:Sujeta></ns1:DesgloseFactura></ns1:TipoDesglose></ns2:FacturaExpedida></ns2:RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas></ns2:SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
Respuesta:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<env:Header/>
<env:Body Id="Body"><siiR:RespuestaLRFacturasEmitidas xmlns:siiR="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/RespuestaSuministro.xsd" xmlns:sii="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroInformacion.xsd"><siiR:Cabecera><sii:IDVersionSii>1.0</sii:IDVersionSii><sii:Titular><sii:NombreRazon>ALEXANDRU CATALIN TRANDAFIR</sii:NombreRazon><sii:NIF>X4378072E</sii:NIF></sii:Titular><sii:TipoComunicacion>A0</sii:TipoComunicacion></siiR:Cabecera><siiR:EstadoEnvio>Incorrecto</siiR:EstadoEnvio><siiR:RespuestaLinea><siiR:IDFactura><sii:IDEmisorFactura><sii:NIF>X4378072E</sii:NIF></sii:IDEmisorFactura><sii:NumSerieFacturaEmisor>SIIDEMO/1</sii:NumSerieFacturaEmisor><sii:FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor>31-12-2017</sii:FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor></siiR:IDFactura><siiR:EstadoRegistro>Incorrecto</siiR:EstadoRegistro><siiR:CodigoErrorRegistro>3000</siiR:CodigoErrorRegistro><siiR:DescripcionErrorRegistro>Factura duplicada</siiR:DescripcionErrorRegistro><siiR:CSV>QSAYUMZV8NM3REGD</siiR:CSV></siiR:RespuestaLinea><siiR:RespuestaLinea><siiR:IDFactura><sii:IDEmisorFactura><sii:NIF>X4378072E</sii:NIF></sii:IDEmisorFactura><sii:NumSerieFacturaEmisor>SIIDEMO/2</sii:NumSerieFacturaEmisor><sii:FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor>31-12-2017</sii:FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor></siiR:IDFactura><siiR:EstadoRegistro>Incorrecto</siiR:EstadoRegistro><siiR:CodigoErrorRegistro>3000</siiR:CodigoErrorRegistro><siiR:DescripcionErrorRegistro>Factura duplicada</siiR:DescripcionErrorRegistro><siiR:CSV>QSAYUMZV8NM3REGD</siiR:CSV></siiR:RespuestaLinea></siiR:RespuestaLRFacturasEmitidas>
</env:Body></env:Envelope>
```

Para facturas recibidas tendrás que:

- Usar el WSDL correspondiente al servicio de facturas recibidas
- Usar el location del entorno pruebas del servicio facturas recibidas que lo encuentras en el WSDL
- Construir la matriz de datos que corresponde a facturas recibidas ya que los de este ejemplo son de emitidas
- Llamar al comando `SuministroLRFacturasRecibidas` en vez de `SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas`

Por último comentarte que te hace falta usar un certificado:

- Paso 1: Consigue un certificado PFX/P12 de tu gestora/asesora de esos que instalas en el navegador para conectarte a la Agencia Tributaria
- Paso 2: Convierte ese certificado de formato PFX a formato PEM. En esta otra respuesta he explicado cómo se convierte el certificado: [Enviar modelo SII a hacienda usando cURL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/128285/enviar-modelo-sii-a-hacienda-usando-curl/131407#131407)

Y para cerrar, si te interesa ver más información sobre cómo trabajar con SII desde PHP, este ebook http://www.aeatsiidesarrolladores.es/ explica tanto la naturaleza de los servicios web como también muestra paso a paso con ejemplos de código en PHP cómo realizar todo el circuito de comunicación con el SII.