# Enviar modelo SII a hacienda usando cURL

Tags: curl, aeat-sii, openssl, certificado-ssl

Estoy completamente desesperado. Intenté tiempo atrás buscar respuesta usando vba, y no conseguí solución.

Volví a la carga intentando usar cURL desde línea de comandos, pero tampoco me funciona. En este caso, os voy a plantear todo el proceso realizado con CURL, el cual según he podido documentarme, debería funcionar. Pero algo se me escapa, porque no consigo que el Web Service de Hacienda reciba mis ficheros

### Exportar Certificado (.pfx)

Para poder usar el certificado, primero de todo hay que exportarlo de mi navegador. Para ello, se puede hacer:

- Configuración de Chrome

  - Gestionar certificados...

    - Exportar la clave privada

      - Intercambio de información personal: PKCS #12 (.PFX)

        - Incluir totos los certificados en la ruta de acceso de certificación (si es posible)
        - Exportar todas las propiedades extendidas
      - Darle contraseña: 12345
      - Darle nombre al archivo: Certificado.pfx

Una vez hecho esto, obtengo un certificado en formato .pfx

### Convertir certificado .pfx a .pem (OpenSSL)

Este formato no es valido para cURL. Por ello, se debe transformar a .pem antes. Y para ello, en todas partes hablan de OpenSSL.
Descargué la versión 1.0.21 25 May 2017 (consultado desde línea de comandos)
Transformo certificado:

```
--Importo certificado PEM (sin key)
C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.exe pkcs12 -in C:\VariasSII\Certificados\Certificado.pfx -out C:\VariasSII\Certificados\Certificado-CL.pem -clcerts -nokeys

--Importo KEY
C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.exe pkcs12 -in C:\VariasSII\Certificados\Certificado.pfx -out C:\VariasSII\Certificados\Certificado-KEY.pem -nocerts

--Importo CA (Esto en muchas partes no se usa. Lo tengo, y puedo ponerlo o no, aunque en cualquiera de los casos no me sirve para que funcione el envío
C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.exe pkcs12 -in C:\VariasSII\Certificados\Certificado.pfx -out C:\VariasSII\Certificados\Certificado-CA.pem -cacerts -nokeys
```

### Envío (usando cURL)

Finalmente, con esta instrucción se debería poder enviar ficheros XML a Hacienda:

```
curl --data C:\VariasSII\TEST.xml --output C:\VariasSII\respuesta.xml --cert C:\VariasSII\Certificados\Certificado-CL.pem --key C:\VariasSII\Certificados\Certificado-KEY.pem https://www7.aeat.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fe/SiiFactFEV1SOAP
```

### Respuesta cURL

La respuesta a esta petición es la que sigue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><env:Envelope 
xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><env:Body><env:Fault>
<faultcode>env:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Codigo[1304].No se permite 
contenido en el prólogo. (1,1)</faultstring><detail><callstack>XML no válido o mal formado
WSExcepcion [faultcode=null, detailMap=null, version=0, faultstring=No se permite contenido en el prólogo. (1,1), faultactor=null, faultSubCode=null, reasonText=null, detail=null, nameSpaceUriDetail=null]
at es.aeat.adws.jdit.imp.ws.WSFilterSrvImpl.verificarFirma(WSFilterSrvImpl.java:810)
at es.aeat.adws.jdit.imp.ws.WSFilterSrvImpl.doFilter(WSFilterSrvImpl.java:246)
at es.aeat.adws.jdit.api.ws.WSFilter.doFilter(WSFilter.java:24)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at es.aeat.adht.jdit.imp.infra.JDitFilterSrvImpl.filtroIni(JDitFilterSrvImpl.java:178)
at es.aeat.adht.jdit.imp.infra.JDitFilterSrvImpl.doFilter(JDitFilterSrvImpl.java:86)
at es.aeat.adht.jdit.imp.infra.JDitFilterSrvImpl.doFilter(JDitFilterSrvImpl.java:63)
at es.aeat.adht.jdit.api.filter.JDitFilter.doFilter(JDitFilter.java:24)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:1021)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1143)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:82)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:934)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:262)
at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:958)
at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.wrapHandlerAndExecute(HttpDispatcherLink.java:357)
at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:317)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:471)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:405)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:285)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:256)
at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:174)
at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:83)
at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:504)
at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:574)
at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:929)
at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1018)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1153)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
Caused by: es.aeat.adws.jdit.api.xml.XmlExcepcion: No se permite contenido en el prólogo. (1,1)
at es.aeat.adws.jdit.imp.xml.DomUtilsImpl.isToDoc(DomUtilsImpl.java:85)
at es.aeat.adws.jdit.imp.xml.DomUtilsImpl.isToDoc(DomUtilsImpl.java:51)
at es.aeat.adws.jdit.imp.ws.WSFilterSrvImpl.verificarFirma(WSFilterSrvImpl.java:781)
... 31 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: No se permite contenido en el prólogo.
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
at es.aeat.adws.jdit.imp.xml.DomUtilsImpl.isToDoc(DomUtilsImpl.java:81)
... 33 more
```

Según error, podría parecer que el error está en el fichero XML, pero os lo aseguro que no es así. Ese fichero se puede enviar perfectamente desde el entorno habilitado de la agenciatributaria sin problemas, y también se puede enviar usando una aplicación externa (SoapUI)

### Últimas consideraciones

En alguna página web vi que exportaban CA del certificado para luego usarlo en cURL (añadí antes la instrucción que permitiría extraer el CA). No obstante, en la mayoría de sitios consultados no hacen uso de este CA.

A nivel informativo, utilizar dicho CA me genera el siguiente aviso:

```
curl.exe [...] --cacert C:\VariasSII\Certificados\Certificado-CA.pem

curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain

More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

Estoy convencido que el problema está en el certificado. Pero teniendo en cuenta que el certificado.pfx funciona bien (lo he probado con SoapUI, y lo he exportado a otro ordenador pudiendo utilizar en dicho ordenador ese certificado sin problemas)
... me quedaría por pensar que algo está mal al convertir ese .pfx en .pem al usar OpenSSL?
Los pasos en OpenSSL y cURL los encontré en la red, y lo he contrastado con todas las fuentes posibles. A la gente les funciona bien. Pero yo no avanzo de aquí.

Ojalá alguien pueda arrojar algo de luz a este problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifico la respuesta ya que al parecer el problema en tu caso no era con el certificado sino con los parámetros de cURL.

### Cómo realizar la llamada desde cURL

```
curl --cert ./ALEXANDRU_CATALIN_bundle.pem --header "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8" --header "SOAPAction: SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas" --data @datos_xml.txt -v https://www7.aeat.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fe/SiiFactFEV1SOAP
```

Por partes:

- `--cert ./ALEXANDRU_CATALIN_bundle.pem` establece el certificado
- `--header "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8"` indica tipo de contenido enviado
- `--header "SOAPAction: SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas"` indica el comando del webservice al que queremos llamar
- `--data @datos_xml.txt` especifica el fichero con los datos, **IMPORTANTE** al parecer el `@` que hay delante de la ruta del fichero es un detalle muy importante ya que es lo que le indica a cURL que debe leer de un fichero

Contenido `datos_xml.txt`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroInformacion.xsd" xmlns:ns2="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroLR.xsd">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns2:SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas>
      <ns1:Cabecera>
        <ns1:IDVersionSii>1.0</ns1:IDVersionSii>
        <ns1:Titular>
          <ns1:NombreRazon>ALEXANDRU CATALIN TRANDAFIR</ns1:NombreRazon>
          <ns1:NIF>X4378072E</ns1:NIF>
        </ns1:Titular>
        <ns1:TipoComunicacion>A0</ns1:TipoComunicacion>
      </ns1:Cabecera>
      <ns2:RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas>
        <ns1:PeriodoImpositivo>
          <ns1:Ejercicio>2017</ns1:Ejercicio>
          <ns1:Periodo>12</ns1:Periodo>
        </ns1:PeriodoImpositivo>
        <ns2:IDFactura>
          <ns1:IDEmisorFactura>
            <ns1:NIF>X4378072E</ns1:NIF>
          </ns1:IDEmisorFactura>
          <ns1:NumSerieFacturaEmisor>SIIDEMO/1</ns1:NumSerieFacturaEmisor>
          <ns1:FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor>31-12-2017</ns1:FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor>
        </ns2:IDFactura>
        <ns2:FacturaExpedida>
          <ns1:TipoFactura>F1</ns1:TipoFactura>
          <ns1:FechaOperacion>31-12-2017</ns1:FechaOperacion>
          <ns1:ClaveRegimenEspecialOTrascendencia>01</ns1:ClaveRegimenEspecialOTrascendencia>
          <ns1:ImporteTotal>1210</ns1:ImporteTotal>
          <ns1:DescripcionOperacion>Compra ordenador portátil</ns1:DescripcionOperacion>
          <ns1:Contraparte>
            <ns1:NombreRazon>HeavyDots SL</ns1:NombreRazon>
            <ns1:NIF>B66544586</ns1:NIF>
          </ns1:Contraparte>
          <ns1:TipoDesglose>
            <ns1:DesgloseFactura>
              <ns1:Sujeta>
                <ns1:NoExenta>
                  <ns1:TipoNoExenta>S1</ns1:TipoNoExenta>
                  <ns1:DesgloseIVA>
                    <ns1:DetalleIVA>
                      <ns1:TipoImpositivo>21</ns1:TipoImpositivo>
                      <ns1:BaseImponible>500</ns1:BaseImponible>
                      <ns1:CuotaRepercutida>105</ns1:CuotaRepercutida>
                    </ns1:DetalleIVA>
                    <ns1:DetalleIVA>
                      <ns1:TipoImpositivo>21</ns1:TipoImpositivo>
                      <ns1:BaseImponible>500</ns1:BaseImponible>
                      <ns1:CuotaRepercutida>105</ns1:CuotaRepercutida>
                    </ns1:DetalleIVA>
                  </ns1:DesgloseIVA>
                </ns1:NoExenta>
              </ns1:Sujeta>
            </ns1:DesgloseFactura>
          </ns1:TipoDesglose>
        </ns2:FacturaExpedida>
      </ns2:RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas>
      <ns2:RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas>
        <ns1:PeriodoImpositivo>
          <ns1:Ejercicio>2017</ns1:Ejercicio>
          <ns1:Periodo>12</ns1:Periodo>
        </ns1:PeriodoImpositivo>
        <ns2:IDFactura>
          <ns1:IDEmisorFactura>
            <ns1:NIF>X4378072E</ns1:NIF>
          </ns1:IDEmisorFactura>
          <ns1:NumSerieFacturaEmisor>SIIDEMO/2</ns1:NumSerieFacturaEmisor>
          <ns1:FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor>31-12-2017</ns1:FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor>
        </ns2:IDFactura>
        <ns2:FacturaExpedida>
          <ns1:TipoFactura>F1</ns1:TipoFactura>
          <ns1:FechaOperacion>31-12-2017</ns1:FechaOperacion>
          <ns1:ClaveRegimenEspecialOTrascendencia>01</ns1:ClaveRegimenEspecialOTrascendencia>
          <ns1:ImporteTotal>1210</ns1:ImporteTotal>
          <ns1:DescripcionOperacion>Compra ordenador portátil</ns1:DescripcionOperacion>
          <ns1:Contraparte>
            <ns1:NombreRazon>HeavyDots SL</ns1:NombreRazon>
            <ns1:NIF>B66544586</ns1:NIF>
          </ns1:Contraparte>
          <ns1:TipoDesglose>
            <ns1:DesgloseFactura>
              <ns1:Sujeta>
                <ns1:NoExenta>
                  <ns1:TipoNoExenta>S1</ns1:TipoNoExenta>
                  <ns1:DesgloseIVA>
                    <ns1:DetalleIVA>
                      <ns1:TipoImpositivo>21</ns1:TipoImpositivo>
                      <ns1:BaseImponible>500</ns1:BaseImponible>
                      <ns1:CuotaRepercutida>105</ns1:CuotaRepercutida>
                    </ns1:DetalleIVA>
                    <ns1:DetalleIVA>
                      <ns1:TipoImpositivo>21</ns1:TipoImpositivo>
                      <ns1:BaseImponible>500</ns1:BaseImponible>
                      <ns1:CuotaRepercutida>105</ns1:CuotaRepercutida>
                    </ns1:DetalleIVA>
                  </ns1:DesgloseIVA>
                </ns1:NoExenta>
              </ns1:Sujeta>
            </ns1:DesgloseFactura>
          </ns1:TipoDesglose>
        </ns2:FacturaExpedida>
      </ns2:RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas>
    </ns2:SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Respuesta:

```
*   Trying 195.76.38.173...
* Connected to www7.aeat.es (195.76.38.173) port 443 (#0)
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: C:\xampp\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / AES256-SHA256
* Server certificate:
*        subject: description=CAM-SSL-SW; L=MADRID; ST=MADRID; serialNumber=Q2826000H; OU=INFORMATICA TRIBUTARIA; O=AGENCIA ESTATAL DE ADMINISTRACIÓN TRIBUTARIA; CN=*.aeat.es; C=ES
*        start date: Nov  5 07:12:54 2015 GMT
*        expire date: Nov  4 07:12:54 2018 GMT
*        subjectAltName: www7.aeat.es matched
*        issuer: C=ES; OU=AC CAMERFIRMA; O=AC Camerfirma S.A.; serialNumber=A82743287; L=Madrid (see current address at https://www.camerfirma.com/address); CN=Camerfirma Corporate Server II - 2015
*        SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fe/SiiFactFEV1SOAP HTTP/1.1
> Host: www7.aeat.es
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
> SOAPAction: SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas
> Content-Length: 4824
> Expect: 100-continue
>
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Thu, 18 Jan 2018 00:49:53 GMT
< X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.1
< DIT-Servidor: WLP00401
< X-UA-Compatible: IE=7
< DIT-Tarea: 17577
< DIT-Codigo-Respuesta: 0
< DIT-NIU: 8093634366
< Content-Length: 1838
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=s1~0001dmDLVUkaddMP4RFOx4oMUB4:wlp004_wlp001; Path=/wlpl/; Secure; HttpOnly
< Set-Cookie: aeat_id_usr_sede=%7B%22tipoAcceso%22%3A%22C%22%2C%22fechaYHora%22%3A%2220180118004953432%22%2C%22nombre%22%3A%22TRANDAFIR%20ALEXANDRU%20CATALIN%22%7D; Path=/; Domain=.agenciatributaria.gob.aeat; Secure
< Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-cache="set-cookie, set-cookie2"
< Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
<
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<env:Header/>
<env:Body Id="Body"><siiR:RespuestaLRFacturasEmitidas xmlns:siiR="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/RespuestaSuministro.xsd" xmlns:sii="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroInformacion.xsd"><siiR:Cabecera><sii:IDVersionSii>1.0</sii:IDVersionSii><sii:Titular><sii:NombreRazon>ALEXANDRU CATALIN TRANDAFIR</sii:NombreRazon><sii:NIF>X4378072E</sii:NIF></sii:Titular><sii:TipoComunicacion>A0</sii:TipoComunicacion></siiR:Cabecera><siiR:EstadoEnvio>Incorrecto</siiR:EstadoEnvio><siiR:RespuestaLinea><siiR:IDFactura><sii:IDEmisorFactura><sii:NIF>X4378072E</sii:NIF></sii:IDEmisorFactura><sii:NumSerieFacturaEmisor>SIIDEMO/1</sii:NumSerieFacturaEmisor><sii:FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor>31-12-2017</sii:FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor></siiR:IDFactura><siiR:EstadoRegistro>Incorrecto</siiR:EstadoRegistro><siiR:CodigoErrorRegistro>3000</siiR:CodigoErrorRegistro><siiR:DescripcionErrorRegistro>Factura duplicada</siiR:DescripcionErrorRegistro><siiR:CSV>QSAYUMZV8NM3REGD</siiR:CSV></siiR:RespuestaLinea><siiR:RespuestaLinea><siiR:IDFactura><sii:IDEmisorFactura><sii:NIF>X4378072E</sii:NIF></sii:IDEmisorFactura><sii:NumSerieFacturaEmisor>SIIDEMO/2</sii:NumSerieFacturaEmisor><sii:FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor>31-12-2017</sii:FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor></siiR:IDFactura><siiR:EstadoRegistro>Incorrecto</siiR:EstadoRegistro><siiR:CodigoErrorRegistro>3000</siiR:CodigoErrorRegistro><siiR:DescripcionErrorRegistro>Factura duplicada</siiR:DescripcionErrorRegistro><siiR:CSV>QSAYUMZV8NM3REGD</siiR:CSV></siiR:RespuestaLinea></siiR:RespuestaLRFacturasEmitidas>
</env:Body></env:Envelope>* Connection #0 to host www7.aeat.es left intact
```

### Como obtener certificado válido PEM bundle

Te cuento los pasos para obtener un certificado válido, pero antes dos notas:

1. En mi caso lo estoy preparando para usarlo con el SoapClient de PHP que también necesita el formato PEM
2. En mi caso uso el archivo .PFX original que me mandó mi gestora, es decir, no fue importado/exportado al/del navegador aunque entiendo que con el tuyo exportado también debería funcionar siempre que sea un PFX/P12 válido

Allá vamos..

Estos son los comandos a ejecutar con `openssl`:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in archivo.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out archivo_mycert.pem -password pass:"contraseña"
openssl pkcs12 -in archivo.pfx -nocerts -nodes -out archivo_mykey.pem -password pass:"contraseña"
```

Con estos comandos extraes por un lado el certificado y por otro, la clave privada, ejemplos:

Contenido `archivo_mycert.pem`:

```
Bag Attributes
    localKeyID: 01 00 00 00 
    1.3.6.1.4.1.311.17.3.92: 00 08 00 00 
    1.3.6.1.4.1.311.17.3.20: 2A 87 AA 0D B3 2B B8 0B 9F 63 51 6D 29 18 27 68 67 9C 50 F2 
    1.3.6.1.4.1.311.17.3.71: 47 00 45 00 53 00 54 00 49 00 4F 00 2D 00 50 00 43 00 00 00 
    1.3.6.1.4.1.311.17.3.75: 34 00 46 00 46 00 33 00 32 00 31 00 42 00 35 00 42 00 46 00 31 00 39 00 39 00 37 00 38 00 46 00 43 00 46 00 31 00 31 00 33 00 37 00 44 00 41 00 35 00 45 00 39 00 32 00 42 00 34 00 46 00 39 00 5F 00 00 00 
...
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGmjCCBYKgAwIBAgIQFciYgGKGJNVYbjZryy+gCDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBL
...
xdl/6mx4Kb3K/7JElDg=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Contenido `archivo_mykey.pem`:

```
Bag Attributes
    localKeyID: 01 00 00 00 
    friendlyName: le-d65c3786-5ca1-4b92-a149-82acdd8fd1f3
    Microsoft CSP Name: Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider
Key Attributes
    X509v3 Key Usage: 80 
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKcwggSjAgEAAoIBAQCZBqn8nYbmOLjR
...
Z2orfXHJGDmzf7eGfC4r0g4=
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

A continuación lo que debes hacer es crear un tercer archivo que lo llamaremos `archivo_bundle.pem` y donde dentro de este fichero pegamos los contenidos del certificado y del key, quedando algo así:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGmjCCBYKgAwIBAgIQFciYgGKGJNVYbjZryy+gCDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBL
...
xdl/6mx4Kb3K/7JElDg=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKcwggSjAgEAAoIBAQCZBqn8nYbmOLjR
...
Z2orfXHJGDmzf7eGfC4r0g4=
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Listo, ahora usarás el fichero `archivo_bundle.pem` como parámetro en tu llamada cURL o SoapClient.

Por último comentarte que en http://www.aeatsiidesarrolladores.es/ he redactado un ebook técnico de la implementación del SII. Contiene ejemplos de código en PHP y una mini aplicación que tiene todo el circuito de comunicación con el SII a la que tan solo le hace falta colgarla en un servidor y dejarle un certificado en formato PFX y ya es operativa. Quizás te interese echarle un vistazo! Suerte! :-)

Comment: Solamente agregar que la fuente original donde yo encontré mi respuesta cuándo la estaba buscando fue este otro post de StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33101153/royal-mail-shipping-api-soap-connection-pem-certificates-query

Comment: Gracias por la aportación. Es una respuesta interesante. Lamentablemente tampoco me funcionó T_T. La respuesta en este caso sigue siendo la misma. Creo que la unión tal y como la hiciste es contrastable con el método que yo utilizaba (separando --cert y --key en cUrl)

Comment: @BeniGls he actualizado la respuesta con la solución correcta, como en tu descripción decías que era muy probable problema del certificado no presté atención que el webservice sí te respondió, lo que quiere decir que el certificado ha funcionado ya que si no no te respondería, finalmente el problema estaba en los parámetros de cURL, suerte! :-)

Comment: Brillante! todo este tiempo tan cerca, y simplemente no le di la importancia que tenía esa '@' en --data
Mil gracias, esto me permite avanzar después de meses buscando alternativas de envío.

Comment: Jaja me alergo! A veces no hay que dejarse rendido, hay que tener fe y encontrar la solución como sea! :) Al final estás decidido en qué entorno vas a montar tu aplicación SII? cUrl? vb? php/web? ya que creo que intentaste de varias maneras

Comment: Por ahora lo tengo ya preparado para vba, ya que es el código base con el que trabajo, y no necesito de ninguna instalación adicional. Y si localizara algún problema usaría curl como intermediario para hacer los envíos desde vba :)