# SOAPCLIENT php, como añadir certificado .pem en la cabecera

Tags: php, soap

Es la primera vez que escribo aquí porque no sé que más probar ya...

Tengo que integrar un servicio para comunicarme con la **dgt** en la cual indico una matrícula y me devuelve unos datos.

Desde el entorno de **`SoapUi`** no hay problemas, porque desde las configuraciones te permite crear un `header` con el **`certificado.pem`** y añadirlo sin problemas. De forma que queda más o menos así :

```
      <ns1:idUsuario>888888</ns1:idUsuario>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <ns1:idOrganismoResponsable>88</ns1:idOrganismoResponsable>
        <ns1:idResponsable>88888</ns1:idResponsable>
        <ns1:version>4</ns1:version>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <ns1:tasa>8888888</ns1:tasa>
        <ns1:CriteriosConsultaVehiculo>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <ns1:matricula>1265dxz</ns1:matricula>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <ns1:bastidor/>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <ns1:nive>?</ns1:nive>
     </ns1:CriteriosConsultaVehiculo>
  </ns1:SolicitudConsultaVehiculoAtex></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

El problema es al realizarlo desde **`php`**, He intentado crear un **`soapHeader`** y meterselo tal cual como me lo pinta en **`SoapUi`** pero me da acceso denegado, Porque en verdad no estoy añadiendo la clave sino que estoy metiendo un **`string`** con el contenido que me aparece en el **`SoapUi`** al añadir la cabecera.

He intentado también con los parametros :

```
'local_cert' =>'C:\\Users\\Dani\\Desktop\\certificado_bueno_camiondirecto_dario\\cert_camion.PFX.pem',
'passphrase'=>'xxxx',
```

Y también me da error pues no se me añade en el `header` .

Alguna solución?

Gracias

Comment: Tienes permisos de lectura del archivo pem sobre el directorio, es decir si el servidor puede acceder a el y leerlo sin problema, otra es que agregues el certificado a tu lista de certificados confiables en windows

Comment: Checa esta liga http://php.net/stream_context_create, haber si te puede ayudar en algo

Comment: cabo de instalar el certificado en mi máquina y sigue igual. Y tema de permisos no creo que sea porque lo estoy realizando en local. En cuanto a lo del stream_context he probado y me dá el mismo error: dGT::tarificar() Error: Dgt::callService() Error: No se ha encontrado el certificado firmante en el documento XML.

Comment: Estoy liado con esto mismo de la DGT que comentas en tu post y ando un poco perdido ya que es la primera vez que trato con SOAP, certificados y tal.. Me podrías echar un cable para orientarme al menos? No te robaré mucho tiempo. **Email: sprindel@hotmail.com** Muchas gracias!

Comment: Yo también he probado a realizar la firma y he tenido una serie de problemas. Has dado con la solución? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: has conseguiste hacer el tema de la DGT, estoy intentandolo yo ahora y me esta volviendo loco. Gracias y un saludo

Answer (score 2):

A mi me funciono esto:

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
try{
    $options = array(
            "exceptions" => true,
            "trace" => 1,
            'encoding'=>'UTF-8',
            'stream_context' => stream_context_create(array(
                    'http' => array(
                            'header' => "Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode($usuario.":".$password)
                    ),
                    "ssl"=>array(
                            "verify_peer"=>true
                            ,"allow_self_signed"=>false
                            ,"cafile"=>"/etc/ssl/certs/mycertificado.pem"
                            ,"verify_depth"=>5
                            )
            ))
    );
    $client = new SoapClient($url,$options);
    $client->__setLocation($url);
    $params = array("param1" => $param1,"param2" => $param2);
    $respuesta = $client->validar($params);
}catch(SoapFault $fault){
    //Error SOAP
    error_log($fault->faultcode." - ".$fault->faultstring);
    $respuesta=trigger_error("SOAP Fault:(faultcode: " . $fault->faultcode . "\n" . "faultstring: " . $fault->faultstring . ")", E_USER_ERROR);    
}
```

Tiene que ir la ruta directa del certificado porque el tipo de `certificado pem` es incompatible con el tipo de `almacen de certificados` que usa php.

Answer (score 0):

Yo tuve que implementar una descarga de archivo de Microdatos de DGT.

https://sedeapl.dgt.gob.es/WEB_IEST_CONSULTA/

Usando este web service:

https://sedeapl.dgt.gob.es/IEST_INTER/MICRODATOS/webService/IEST_descargaFicheroMicrodatos.pdf

La manera tradicional que yo usaba no ha funcionado.

Que era la de convertir el certificado de PFX a PEM y pasarlo como parámetro `local_cert`.

Esto sí funciona con el web service de SII (Suministro Inmediato de Facturas).

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array(
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
    'trace' => true,
    'exceptions' => true,
    'local_cert' => $local_cert,
));
```

Lo que tuve que hacer en cambio es usar otra librería que encontré a partir de este post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55713085/how-to-send-soap-digital-signed-message-using-cert

La librería es esta:

https://github.com/robrichards/wse-php

La instalé vía composer y luego usé el ejemplo de aquí:

https://github.com/robrichards/wse-php/blob/master/examples/soap-wsa-example.php

Lo tuve que adaptar un poco a PHP7 y al web service de DGT y me funcionó a la primera.

El certificado en vez de pasar el bundle, es decir, certificado y clave en un único archivo, se pasan dos archivos, el pem del cert y el pem de la clave, ambos extraidos previamente desde el PFX con el tool de commandline de openssl.

Para quién no sepa como convertir el certificado en este otro post lo explico:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/131407/1143