# ¿Cómo actualizar mi aplicación PHP a la versión 1.1 del SII de AEAT?

Tags: php, xml, webservice, aeat-sii

A partir del 21.07.2018 entra en vigor la versión 1.1 del webservice SII de la Agencia Tributaria de España.

Quién no haya actualizado su aplicación, dejará de poder enviar las facturas.

Me gustaría saber cuales son los pasos imprescindibles para realizar la actualización.

Para la versión 1.0 he usado el ejemplo de la respuesta de esta pregunta:

[Enviar XML al web service de SII AEAT (PHP SOAP)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/81686/enviar-xml-al-web-service-de-sii-aeat-php-soap)

Answer (score 0):

Para responder voy a usar el mismo script que has usado para la versión 1.0 pero cambiando las cosas imprescindibles para que sea compatible con la 1.1:

Cambio 1:

- Cambia la URL de la definición del servicio

https://www.agenciatributaria.es/static_files/AEAT/Contenidos_Comunes/La_Agencia_Tributaria/Modelos_y_formularios/Suministro_inmediato_informacion/FicherosSuministros/V_1_1/SuministroFactEmitidas.wsdl

Cambio 2:

- Cambia el parámetro `IDVersionSii` de tu llamada al valor `1.1`

Cambio 3:

- Cambia el campo `PeriodoImpositivo` y pasa a llamarse `PeriodoLiquidacion`

Script completo:

```
<?php

// Ejemplo script para facturas emitidas
// Ruta a certificado previamente convertido de PFX a PEM
$local_cert = 'C:\Projects\aeat-sii-desarrolladores\demo-script\certificados\ALEXANDRU_CATALIN_bundle.pem';

// URL definición servicio de facturas emitidas
$wsdl = 'https://www.agenciatributaria.es/static_files/AEAT/Contenidos_Comunes/La_Agencia_Tributaria/Modelos_y_formularios/Suministro_inmediato_informacion/FicherosSuministros/V_1_1/SuministroFactEmitidas.wsdl';

// Instanciar el cliente SOAP
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array(
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
    'trace' => true,
    'exceptions' => true,
    'local_cert' => $local_cert,
        ));

// Cambiar a entorno pruebas
$location = 'https://www7.aeat.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fe/SiiFactFEV1SOAP';
$client->__setLocation($location);

// Construir datos
$datos = array(
    'Cabecera' =>
    array(
        'IDVersionSii' => '1.1',
        'Titular' =>
        array(
            'NombreRazon' => 'ALEXANDRU CATALIN TRANDAFIR',
            'NIF' => 'X4378072E',
        ),
        'TipoComunicacion' => 'A0',
    ),
    'RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas' =>
    array(
        0 =>
        array(
            'PeriodoLiquidacion' =>
            array(
                'Ejercicio' => '2017',
                'Periodo' => '12',
            ),
            'IDFactura' =>
            array(
                'IDEmisorFactura' =>
                array(
                    'NIF' => 'X4378072E',
                ),
                'NumSerieFacturaEmisor' => 'SIIDEMO/1',
                'FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor' => '31-12-2017',
            ),
            'FacturaExpedida' =>
            array(
                'TipoFactura' => 'F1',
                'ClaveRegimenEspecialOTrascendencia' => '01',
                'ImporteTotal' => 1210,
                'DescripcionOperacion' => 'Compra ordenador portátil',
                'FechaOperacion' => '31-12-2017',
                'Contraparte' =>
                array(
                    'NombreRazon' => 'HeavyDots SL',
                    'NIF' => 'B66544586',
                ),
                'TipoDesglose' =>
                array(
                    'DesgloseFactura' =>
                    array(
                        'Sujeta' =>
                        array(
                            'NoExenta' =>
                            array(
                                'TipoNoExenta' => 'S1',
                                'DesgloseIVA' =>
                                array(
                                    'DetalleIVA' =>
                                    array(
                                        0 =>
                                        array(
                                            'TipoImpositivo' => 21,
                                            'BaseImponible' => 500,
                                            'CuotaRepercutida' => 105,
                                        ),
                                        1 =>
                                        array(
                                            'TipoImpositivo' => 21,
                                            'BaseImponible' => 500,
                                            'CuotaRepercutida' => 105,
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);

// Definir comando
$comando = 'SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas';

// Relizar llamada
$response = null;
$e = null;

try {
  $response = $client->$comando($datos);
} catch (Exception $e) {

}

if ($e instanceof Exception) {

  $error = $e->getMessage();
  $error_detalles = $e->getTraceAsString();

  echo('Error:');
  echo($error);
  echo '<br>';

  echo('Detalles error:');
  echo($error_detalles);
  echo '<br>';
}

$peticion_xml = $client->__getLastRequest();
$respuesta = $client->__getLastResponse();

echo('Petición:<br>');
echo '<pre>' . htmlentities($peticion_xml) . '</pre>';

echo('Respuesta:<br>');
echo '<pre>' . htmlentities($respuesta) . '</pre>';
```

Como se puede notar, los cambios imprescindibles son menores.

Lo que pasa es que dependiendo de cuántas características y campos del SII requiere tu aplicación, puede ser que necesites realizar una lista mucho más amplia de modificaciones.

### Listado completo de cosa que cambian en la versión 1.1 del SII de la AEAT:

- Se renombran estas etiquetas:

  - `<PeriodoImpositivo>` se renombra a `<PeriodoLiquidacion>`
  - `<EmitidaPorTerceros>` se renombra a `<EmitidaPorTercerosODestinatario>`
  - `<ImporteTransmisionSujetoAIVA>` se renombra a `<ImporteTransmisionInmueblesSujetoAIVA>`
- En el libro registro de facturas recibidas se crea un nuevo tipo de factura `LC` que se denomina `Aduanas - Liquidación complementaria`.
- Se crea la etiqueta en el libro de facturas expedidas `<FacturaSinIdentifDestinatarioAritculo6.1.d>` para identificar las facturas completas en las que no es obligatorio identificar al destinatario
- Se crea la etiqueta en el libro registro de facturas expedidas y recibidas `<FacturaSimplificadaArticulos7.2_7.3>` para identificar las facturas simplificadas que identifican al destinatario de acuerdo con los apartados 2 y 3 del artículo 7 del RD 1619/2012
- Se crea la etiqueta en el libro registro de facturas expedidas `<FacturacionDispAdicionalTerceraYsextayDelMercadoOrganizadoDelGas>` para identificar si la factura ha sido emitida por un tercero de acuerdo a una exigencia normativa (disposición adicional tercera y sexta Reglamento por el que se regulan las obligaciones de facturación o normativa del mercado organizado del gas).
- Se incluye una nueva clave en el campo "medio de pago/cobro", será la clave 05 "cobro o pago por domiciliación".
- En el libro de emitidas dentro del bloque `<TipoDesglose>` se añade la etiqueta `<DetalleExenta>` para permitir el desglose del importe exento en función de las distintas causas de exención que pasan a ser compatibles

  - Traducido al Castellano:
  - Este bloque ahora permite múltiples grupos de `CausaExencion` y `BaseImponible`
- Se añade en los libros de emitidas, recibidas, bienes de inversión y determinadas operaciones intracomunitarias una etiqueta adicional de contenido libre denominada `<RefExterna>` con el objetivo de que se pueda añadir información interna de la empresa asociada al registro de la factura.
- Se crea el "SuministroInmueblesAdicionales.wsdl" que describe el envío de inmuebles adicionales cuando una factura tenga más de 15 inmuebles, que son los permitidos en el envío XML de facturas emitidas. Se enviará un XML específico con el resto de los inmuebles.
- Se crea la etiqueta `<NumRegistroAcuerdoFacturacion>` en los libros de bienes de inversión y determinadas operaciones intracomunitarias
- Se crea el bloque `<EntidadSucedida>` en los libros de emitidas, recibidas, bienes de inversión, determinadas operaciones intracomunitarias y suministro de otras operaciones con trascendencia tributaria para identificar los registros de facturación realizados por una entidad en su condición de sucesora de otra entidad por operaciones de reestructuración societaria.
- Se crea la etiqueta `<RegPrevioGGEEoREDEMEoCompetencia>` en los libros de emitidas, recibidas y determinadas operaciones intracomunitarias para aquellos registros de facturación con dificultades para enviarse en plazo por no tener constancia del cambio de condición a GGEE, de la inclusión en REDEME o de un cambio en la competencia inspectora
- Se crea la etiqueta `<Macrodato>` en los libros de emitidas y recibidas para identificar aquellas facturas con importe de la factura superior a un umbral de 100.000.000 euros
- Se crean los nuevos tipos de comunicación `A5` y `A6` para el libro de facturas emitidas. `A5` para registrar las devoluciones del IVA de viajeros y `A6` si estos registros se tienen que modificar.
- Se incluyen periodos trimestrales

  - Lo que quiere decir es que como período antes solo podía ser mensual o anual, pero ahora puede ser también trimestral. Interesante para empresas que tienen IVA trimestral.

### Recursos oficiales

Dejo aquí link a la documentación oficial de la versión 1.1:

[Versión 1.1. - A partir del 01/07/2018](https://www.agenciatributaria.es/AEAT.internet/Inicio/Ayuda/Modelos__Procedimientos_y_Servicios/Ayuda_P_G417____IVA__Llevanza_de_libros_registro__SII_/Ayuda_tecnica/Informacion_tecnica_SII/Version_1_1____A_partir_del_01_07_2018/Version_1_1____A_partir_del_01_07_2018.shtml)

### Recursos adicionales

Si te interesa obtener un script en PHP que es ya funcional y que cubre todo el circuito de comunicación con SII que una aplicación necesita, te recomiendo este ebook que trae incluida una demo en PHP:

[Ebook SII - Guía para desarrolladores](http://www.aeatsiidesarrolladores.es/)

También es recomendable para nuevos desarrollos de SII si es la primera vez que tienes que integrarlo ya que te ayudará a entenderlo más rápidamente.