# Evitar que el certificado usado en una instancia SoapClient sea público

Tags: php, laravel, webservice, soap

He seguido la siguiente respuesta para hacer peticiones a un WS soap de la AEAT: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/131481/202581

Como dice la respuesta, he creado el certificado para consumir dicho WS y lo he tenido que colocar en el servidor.

Con la URL del certificado, cualquiera puede descargarlo. Es un certificado que incluye la clave y supongo que esto no es nada recomendable que sea accesible públicamente .. ¿Correcto?

Me gustaría hacer el dicho certificado no sea accesible públicamente pero si funcione con soapClient, cosa que no he conseguido.

Utilizo Laravel 5.2, he intentado varias cosas, entre ellas:

- Almacenar el certificado en un carpeta no pública y con una ruta, descargar el fichero si está conectado. Al instanciar el SoapClient apuntar a esta ruta, pero no funciona. Me he basado en esta respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24191933/13046827
- Almacenar el certificado en storage/app, que es el disco local no publico por defecto de laravel. Pasar al constructor del SoapClint la url que devuelve: `Storage::disk('local')->url('nombre-certificado.pem')`

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Puedes colocar un archivo `.htaccess` dentro de la carpeta donde está el certificado para evitar que se pueda acceder por web. [Algunos ejemplos](https://clientes.atlanticadigital.net/knowledgebase/305/Bloquear-acceso-a-archivos-con-htaccess.html)

Comment: No me ha funcionado, he creado el fichero .htaccess dentro de la carpeta donde tengo el certificado y se sigue teniendo acceso públicamente. Al acceder a 'mi-dominio.com/carpeta-certificado/.htaccess' y sin crear el .htaccess, ya me devuelve un forbiden, por lo que supongo que ya hay un .htaccess en el raiz del servidor que lo hereda cada una de las carpetas.

Answer (score 2):

Después de darle bastantes vueltas he encontrado la solución.

Colocar el certificado en uno de los discos de almacenamiento privados de laravel  y pasar la url así:

```
$local_cert_url = \Storage::disk('local')->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix()."nombre-certificado.pem"; 

$soapClientOptions = [                
            "location"      => $urlDestino,
            'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
            'trace' => true,
            'local_cert' => $local_cert_url,
];
return new SoapClient($this->wsdl, $soapClientOptions);
```